# How to set child process' environment variable in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, environment-variables, target

I would like to change this Makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
PATH  := node_modules/.bin:$(PATH)

boot:
    @supervisor         \
      --harmony         \
      --watch etc,lib       \
      --extensions js,json      \
      --no-restart-on error     \
        lib

test:
    NODE_ENV=test mocha         \
      --harmony             \
      --reporter spec       \
        test

clean:
    @rm -rf node_modules

.PHONY: test clean
```

to:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
PATH  := node_modules/.bin:$(PATH)

boot:
    @supervisor         \
      --harmony         \
      --watch etc,lib       \
      --extensions js,json      \
      --no-restart-on error     \
        lib

test: NODE_ENV=test
test:
    mocha                   \
      --harmony             \
      --reporter spec       \
        test

clean:
    @rm -rf node_modules

.PHONY: test clean
```

Unfortunately the second one does not work (the node process still runs with the default `NODE_ENV`.

What did I miss?

Comment: Your `Unfortunately` comment stems from a misunderstanding between an environment variable versus a `Makefile` variable.  The best way to prove that an environment variable has been set, is to query this environment variable inside another program that `make` wil call. Only doing `echo $(BLAH)` is merely evaluating Makefile's key/value mechanism inside the Makefile. In python, you can `print(os.getenv("MURDOC"))`  to truly query the environment variable.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Make variables are not exported into the environment of processes make invokes... by default.  However you can use make's `export` to force them to do so.  Change:

```
test: NODE_ENV = test
```

to this:

```
test: export NODE_ENV = test
```

(assuming you have a sufficiently modern version of GNU make >= 3.77 ).

Comment: I have GNU make 3.81, and `all: <\n\t>export PROJ_ROOT=$(CURDIR)<\n\t>echo $(PROJ_ROOT)<\n>` outputs the correct expansion for the first row, but only `echo` for the second one. `PROJ_ROOT` is not set after running make. Spaces around `=` give "bad variable name" for export. Having the first row as prerequisite as in your example gives "commands commence before first target"

Comment: @Gauthier yes of course.  That's not what I wrote.  You added a <\n\t> after the `all:`, which is not in my example.  My example is intended to be used as written: it's defining a target-specific variable, _NOT_ adding a command to the recipe.  Also you cannot use a recipe and a target-specific variable on a target at the same time: you have to write the target twice.  See the second example in the question, and ask a new question if this doesn't help explain it: there's not enough space or formatting in comments.

Comment: What about multiple variables?

Comment: Each variable has to be set on its own separate line in the makefile.

Comment: That's fine but your added it to the head of target. Just listing them in context of target won't work? Because it doesn't work for me

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.  Probably you should file a new question rather than asking in the comments here.

Comment: How modern is modern?

Comment: Target-specific variables were added in GNU make 3.77.  They are exportable as of GNU make 3.81.  See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS

Answer (score 211):

As [MadScientist pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23845391/3682217), you can export individual variables with:

```
export MY_VAR = foo  # Available for all targets
```

Or export variables for a specific target ([target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)):

```
my-target: export MY_VAR_1 = foo
my-target: export MY_VAR_2 = bar
my-target: export MY_VAR_3 = baz

my-target: dependency_1 dependency_2
  echo do something
```

---

You can also specify the `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` target to—you guessed it!—EXPORT ALL THE THINGS!!!:

```
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:

MY_VAR_1 = foo
MY_VAR_2 = bar
MY_VAR_3 = baz

test:
  @echo $$MY_VAR_1 $$MY_VAR_2 $$MY_VAR_3
```

see [.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eEXPORT_005fALL_005fVARIABLES)

Comment: Oddly enough I did test it earlier that showed it worked.. (not sure why now..) I can go back and delete the comment I guess..

Comment: @AnthonyC It works because there are two `MY_VAR`s: one is makefile variable accessed as `${MY_VAR}` and another one is bash exported variable, accessed as `$$MY_VAR`

Comment: Useful. But cannot find a way to export only a set of variables.

Comment: Note if the variable already exists in your makefile and you just want to export it to another command, you can use the syntax `export var ?=` without assigning a new value

Comment: .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES is right answer

Comment: Does exporting in a target pass that variable to it's dependencies as well? In your example; does dependency_1 and dependency_2 have MY_VAR_1 etc. in their environment?

Comment: `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is "right answer" only if we ignore the fact the question most likely demonstrates a case of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) and, more importantly, that exporting _every environment and Make variable_ (yes, both kinds) to every process invoked by Make as part of `make`, is arguably a recipe (no pun intended) for disaster, disaster here loosely meaning subtly "broken" builds that cannot be easily proven (should `$FOOBAR` value be the same for every command?). There's a reason `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` isn't default. It's the right answer alright, to the wrong question.

Comment: oddly enough both `my-target: export V1=1` and `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:` cause my `docker compose up` to start throwing `invalid reference format`

Answer (score 24):

I only needed the environment variables locally to invoke my test command, here's an example setting multiple environment vars in a bash shell, and escaping the dollar sign in `make`.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: test tests
test tests:
    PATH=./node_modules/.bin/:$$PATH \
    JSCOVERAGE=1 \
    nodeunit tests/
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: ThorSummoner, this solution is not as flexible as the approach above. For example, one might wish to have one single rule for invoking a command and then several other rules which modify that behaviour by setting environment variables. Consider:

test:
        cmd

perf: export PERF="yes"
perf: test

If 'cmd' is complicated (and it usually is), then this approach is a lot easier to maintain. Your approach to setting the environment variable in the cmd rule makes this more difficult.

Comment: This solution may not be as flexible indeed, but it is arguably "safer" by some definition since there's no "polluting" of environment indiscriminately, across recipes and shell invocations. In many cases using the shell's own `VAR=... command ...` syntax is exactly what you'd want and what is sufficient. Many environment variables aren't meant to be consumed everywhere and by everything -- some processes expect "their own" variables which only these processes ever would use. The setting of the variable is also at least as explicit as if it were a target-specific variable, so there's that too.

Answer (score 3):

I would re-write the original target test, taking care the needed variable is defined IN THE SAME SUB-PROCESS as the application to launch:

```
test:
    ( NODE_ENV=test mocha --harmony --reporter spec test )
```

Comment: The bracketing (`(` and `)`) here, which creates a sub-shell, serves no meaningful purpose -- normally Make invokes every logical line with own, quite bare (by intent) shell process anyway (so your sub-shell isn't shared with much else you would want to isolate it from) and setting of variables like `NODE_ENV=...` above, will accomplish desired effect much the same -- with or without the subshell -- meaning the only program that will see the `NODE_ENV` variable with value `test` is the `mocha` program Make will invoke as per above (again, with or without the program being run in a sub-shell).