# How to set environment variables in makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

How can I correctly set environment variables in a makefile on Windows? 
I get an error about `CreateProcess`.

```
C:\>make.exe -f build.makefile start
export MALLOC_PERTURB_=110
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, export MALLOC_PERTURB_=110, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
c:\testmake.makefile:4: recipe for target 'start' failed
make: *** [start] Error 2

START: 
    export NODE_ENV=110
    echo $(NODE_ENV)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variable in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843106/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-makefile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear but there are a number of obvious things wrong there.

First off you are running `make` under Windows but writing recipes as if they were shell scripts. That's not the case on Windows (by default at least).

So `export` is being attempted to be run as an external command which is failing (hence the error message about `CreateProcess` failing).

You also don't show us the target that is actually throwing that error.

Additionally you are expecting the `export` and assignment on the first line of the recipe to be in effect for the second line in the recipe body (for the `start` target).

But that isn't the case. Each line in a makefile target's recipe runs in an independent environment. So the `export` and assignment on the first line of the `START` target's recipe doesn't affect the second line.

To do that you need to use one long line or use the [`.ONESHELL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#One-Shell) feature of recent versions of `make`.

Additionally, you are using `$(NODE_ENV)` in your recipe expecting that to be the shell variable you previously set. And even ignoring the previously stated problem that isn't correct.

make is going to expand `$(NODE_ENV)` as a make variable **before** it even runs the recipe at all. You meant `${NODE_ENV}` or `$NODE_ENV` for a shell variable. **That** said for a make recipe you actually need to escape the `$` because `${NODE_ENV}` is *also* a valid make variable expansion. So you need `$${NODE_ENV}` or `$$NODE_ENV` there.

Put together you end up with this (assuming you have a shell somewhere to use).

```
SHELL := /path/to/your/shell

START:
        export NODE_ENV=110; \
        echo "$${NODE_ENV}"
```

(though you don't actually need `export` at that point but that's a different issue entirely).

But if you **don't** have a shell to use then you get to use `cmd.exe` and I'm not sure what the equivalent of `export` there is (though as I just said you don't need it for this) and you end up with something like this (entirely untested):

```
START:
        NODE_ENV=110; \
        echo %NODE_ENV%
```

Comment: This was the solution. .ONESHELL:
START: 
 set NODE_ENV=110
 @echo %NODE_ENV%

Comment: Wow. ONESHELL improved the build speed a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `.ONESHELL` will do that since it uses *far* fewer shell invocations. That said it also drastically changes the semantics of the build (since failures on any given line won't abort the build immediately) at least not without "modif[ing] .SHELLFLAGS to add the -e option to the shell which will cause any failure anywhere in the command line to cause the shell to fail" and `-e` isn't entirely reliable and has a number of caveats.