# How to export environment variables through Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

```
dummy$ cat Makefile 
.PHONY: env

env:
        export v1="def"
        export v2="abc"
```

---

```
dummy$ make env
export v1="def"
export v2="abc"
dummy$ 
dummy$ echo $v1

dummy$ echo $v2

dummy$
```

---

Why `v1` does not display value?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can't we export variables through Makefile?

Comment: I don't think a child process can ever directly change the parent's environment variables.  Maybe you could get hacky with something like `source $(make env)` but at that point I'd see little value in using a makefile at all.

Comment: The term *export* means, send this new environment variable to all sub-processes created by this process.  It does not mean, send this new environment variable to parent processes that created this process.  The latter is impossible (it has nothing to do with make; you can't do it with any process).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843106/how-to-set-child-process-environment-variable-in-makefile